# KDE Plasma: Change hotkey for System Monitor

Tags: hotkeys, kde-plasma

By default KDE Plasma has Ctrl+Escape hotkey for its System Monitor app. I want to use this hotkey for another app.

I tried to search it in SystemSettings -> Hotkeys section, but unable to find it

How can I switch/disable the hotkey for System Monitor?

Comment: Global Shortcuts > KDE Daemon > Show System Activity

Comment: Thank you @ChristophFeck. That's what I need